# Captcha is working fine on localhost , but not online

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, captcha

I'm using simple-php-captcha( https://github.com/claviska/simple-php-captcha ) script on an ajax form in my wordpress theme,
it works fine when it's on localhost but when i upload it on an online host , the captcha codes don't match , every thing works fine , captcha image loads , sessions get created but the captcha code displayed in the image is not the same as when the form is submitted.

functions.php

```
require_once( get_template_directory() . '/libs/captcha/simple-php-captcha.php' );
require_once( get_template_directory() . '/inc/ajax/testimonial.php' );
```

header.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['captcha'] = simple_php_captcha();
```

The html form

```
<form action="<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php"); ?>" class="dw-ajax-form dw-form" method="post" id="send_testimonial">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
    <input type="text" name="job" placeholder="company / job">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email address">
    <textarea type="textarea" name="comment" placeholder="your opinion about us"></textarea>

    <div class="block captcha-image">
        <img src="<?php echo $_SESSION['captcha']["image_src"]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $_SESSION['captcha']["code"]; ?>">
    </div>

    <input type="text" name="captcha" placeholder="enter the code above" autocomplete="off">

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="send_testimonial">
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'send_testimonial', 'send_testimonial_nonce' ); ?>

    <input type="submit" value="send"> <span class="msg" style="margin-right:15px;"></span>
</form>
```

The ajax function ( /inc/ajax/testimonial.php )

```
<?php
/**
 * Testimonial Form Ajax Callbacks
 *
 * @package Wordpress
 * @subpackage Learnfiles-shop Theme
 * @author Dornaweb.com
 */

add_action( 'wp_ajax_send_testimonial', 'dw_send_testimonial' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_send_testimonial', 'dw_send_testimonial' );
function dw_send_testimonial() {
    global $wpdb;
    $message = '';

    $name           = strip_tags( htmlspecialchars( $_POST["name"] ) );
    $job            = strip_tags( htmlspecialchars( $_POST["job"] ) );
    $email          = strip_tags( htmlspecialchars( $_POST["email"] ) );
    $comment        = strip_tags( htmlspecialchars( $_POST["comment"] ) );

    /* captcha */
    $captcha_input  = strtolower( strip_tags( htmlspecialchars( $_POST["captcha"] ) ) );
    $captcha_code = strtolower( $_SESSION['captcha']['code'] );

    /** Validation **/
    if( !$_SESSION['captcha'] || !is_array( $_SESSION['captcha'] ) )
        die( '<span class="error">Somethings wrong</span>' );

    /******************************* IT ALWAYS GIVES ME THIS ERROR WHEN ONLINE , BUT IT WORKS ON LOCALHOST( i also tried it with "!=" operator ) **************/
    if( $captcha_code !== $captcha_input )
        die( '<span class="error">The entered code doesnt match</span>' );
    /**********************************************************************************************************************************************************/

    if (  !isset( $_POST['send_testimonial_nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['send_testimonial_nonce'], 'send_testimonial' ) )
        die('<span class="error">Somethings wrong</span>');

    if( empty( $comment ) )
        die('<span class="error">Please enter your comment</span>');

    if( empty( $name ) )
        die('<span class="error">please enter your name</span>');

    if( !empty( $email ) && !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) )
        die('<span class="error">the entered email doesnt look like an email address</span>');

    if( empty( $name ) && empty( $comment ) )
        die('<span class="error">please fill the form</span>');

    /* send testimonial */
    $testimonial = array(
        'post_title'  => $name,
        'post_status' => 'pending',
        'post_type'   => 'testimonials',
        'post_author' => 1
    );

    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $testimonial );

    update_field( 'job', $job, $post_id );
    update_field( 'email', $email, $post_id );
    update_field( 'comment', $comment, $post_id );

    // form is valid
    if( empty( $message ) )
        $message = '<span class="success">Your comment submitted! thank you.</span>';

    echo $message;
    wp_die();
}
```

edited : 
I've run a test here ( sorry the page is in farsi ) : http://test.dornaweb.ir/ , there is a form in the middle of the page that when you click it , it shows you a `var_dump()` of `$_SESSION['captcha']` , as you can see , the code shown in the image is different is from the code in `var_dump` data , it's like when the form submits the $_SESSION is one step ahead or something like that , the weird thing is when i use the exact same theme on localhost nothing goes wrong!!

Comment: You can see the php-simple-captcha , sourcecode : https://github.com/claviska/simple-php-captcha/blob/master/simple-php-captcha.php

Comment: Maybe a longshot, but it might be worth to check. Is there an additional call to your script from the browser that you are missing? Perhaps some ajax call, perhaps some other call that initiates the whole WP-code? Whenever the captcha code is run again, a new code is set in the session. You may check the access.log file on the server for this. If there are two requests shortly after eachother, that may indicate a request that messes with the captcha...

Comment: i checked it before it is called only once in the header.php ... i've ran a test here : http://test.dornaweb.ir/  ( sorry the page is in farsi ) , just submit the form below the page , it returns a `var_dump` of `$_SESSION['captcha']` , you can see that the code in the image is different from the code in `var_dump( $_SESSION['captcha'] )`

Comment: it's like the $_SESSION is one step ahead when the form submits

Comment: Yeah, my Farsi-skills are not very good... When I ask the browser (FF) for info on the picture, I get a new picture (new code). After submitting, the array in the session indicates that same code. Perhaps there is some code that requests a new image, but does not show it in the page? Were you able to see some odd behavior in the access.log of the server? Sorry, that's as far as I can see...

Comment: here's the access log : http://test.dornaweb.ir/accesslog_test.dornaweb.ir_8_27_2015.gz

Comment: Yes, there it is (probably). For example: lines 319 and 323. Both are a GET request for `/` (the main page), within 2 seconds. First with SO as a referer and than with your site as a referer. That is a second request (without you knowing). How and where that second request is initiated can be very tricky (especially with third party code), but is something to find out yourself. I doubt that someone on SO can help you with that. (Sorry).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is some duplicate request (also judging from the provided access.log). This might be caused by a missing/inaccessible file on the server (which is there/accessible on localhost, thus not causing problems there). If this is requested, some rewrite-code (either within WP or mod_rewrite in .htaccess) rewrites the "failing" request and sends it to the main script. Then, in the main script, the session data gets overwritten with a new captcha...

These issues are sometimes hard to spot. Start at:

- looking for differences between localhost and server
- looking for requests by following each link in the generated html code and checking whether they give the expected response

Perhaps you could also write some debugging messages to either the error.log or some other logging facility. That might also help finding this.

Sorry if this doesn't help you any further...

Comment: thanks for your answer but i couldn't figure it out yet