# JQuery/Ajax hide() and show() issues while hosting on a server

Tags: java, jquery, html, ajax

The code is to display specified tables with respect to the department. The index page contains page links and a div to which the HTML pages are loading.
After loading the page fetching the table id and hiding the table then calling an AJAX to check the hidden table is assigned to that department if so it shows the hidden table, and the process continues till all the table id in the pages are fetched.

```
**JS**

  //loading an html page to a div of index.html
 $('#showData').load('1.Org.html);

//Show hide come here
function showData(department){ 
        $("#showData table").each(function(){
        //$("#testDiv table").each(function(){
            var gid=$(this).attr("id");
            var gidnew=gid.replace(/\./g,'\\.');
            $('#' +gidnew).hide();
            console.log("hide:"+gidnew+"department:"+department);
                $.ajax({
                        url : "/BP/selectGroup/"+department+"/"+gid,
                        async: false,
                        success : function(data){
                            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                            for(i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                                var gid=obj[i].group_id;
                                gid=gid.replace(/\./g,'\\.');
                                $('#'+gid).show();
                                //$("#showData").load('#'+gid);
                                console.log("show"+gid);
                            }
                        $("#loading").hide();
                        },
                        error: function(errorThrown){
                            console.log(errorThrown); // If there was an error it can be seen through the console log. 
                        }

                });
            console.log("aftr ajax::department:"+department);
        });
}
```

Comment: what is the issue mate?

Comment: The code works fine in localhost but while hosting on server it shows nothing on the div even the specified table after show()

Comment: please ctrl+u in your website then click the js file to check  your js exist or not in your folder project, i guess this is the issue

Comment: I checked it is there the js file

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that some configuration or error reporting on your localhost supresses or ignores warnings which doesn't on your server.
Try adding this to your config file :

```
<webServices>
    <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
</webServices>
```

Comment: It shows error in web.xml  while adding the protocol

Comment: Some time even on server it works, but if many login on same time shows hiding of data.

Comment: Is there any problem in the script I have given?

Comment: No,I dont find any flaw in script.Go through this ,if it helps you .  :    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32255012/captcha-is-working-fine-on-localhost-but-not-online

Comment: i didn't use sessions to keep login details

Answer (score 0):

you may need to call to the rest of the codes once you have finished  loading the content to the div. Try using something like this.

```
 $('#showData').load('1.Org.html','', showData(department));
```

Comment: Before calling showData(department) it has to call another ajax to generate a growing table in the 1.Org.html, so it is impossible.